# Using chef-vault in an lwrp

Tags: chef-infra, lwrp

Hey peoples of the internet,

Can someone tell me the magical incantation to get chef-vault working in an LWRP?

So far, I have these pieces and they don't seem to be working.

In my `metadata.rb` file I have

```
depends "chef-vault"
```

in my provider, I've had many different things, but for now I have this:

```
include ChefVaultCookbook
```

And then when I'm trying to use it, both of these did not work:

```
item = chef_vault_item(databag_name, databag_item)
item = ::ChefVaultCookbook::chef_vault_item(databag_name, databag_item)
```

Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong?
Also, is there a good resource for knowing how to do this? Chef's lack of examples makes it difficult for me to figure out how all this fits together.

cheers
Alex

Comment: Do you have a recipe calling the chef-vault default recipe ? This is needed as the `require` and the gem install are done in the recipe. (Quoting README: "Include the recipe before using the Chef Vault library in recipes."). Side note: "both of these did not work" is not really helpful to help you, how did they fail ? any error message ?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to `require 'chef-vault'` somewhere around where you are using the vault data, preferably in the provider.

Comment: The thing I am currently trying to figure out is the possible necessity of:
`chef_gem 'chef-vault' do compile_time true if respond_to? (:compile_time) end`
along the lines of [this post](http://jtimberman.housepub.org/blog/2015/03/20/chef-gem-compile-time-compatibility/)